# Encountered comments is undefined error in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to learn react I keep encountering this error while rendering the post dialog box in the website.

[image: SCREEN SHOT FOR THE ERROR]

comments.js file:

```js
  import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
  import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
  import dayjs from 'dayjs';
  // MUI
  import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
  import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

  const styles = (theme) => ({
    ...theme,
    commentImage: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      height: 100,
      objectFit: 'cover',
      borderRadius: '50%'
    },
    commentData: {
      marginLeft: 20
    }
  });

  class Comments extends Component {
    render() {
      const { comments, classes } = this.props;
      return (
      //Here is the error
        <Grid container>
            {comments.map((comment, index) => {
            const { body, createdAt, userImage, userHandle } = comment;
            return (
              <Fragment key={createdAt}>
                <Grid item sm={12}>
                  <Grid container>
                    <Grid item sm={2}>
                      <img
                        src={userImage}
                        alt="comment"
                        className={classes.commentImage}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item sm={9}>
                      <div className={classes.commentData}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="h5"
                          component={Link}
                          to={`/users/${userHandle}'}
                          color="primary"
                        >
                          {userHandle}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                          {dayjs(createdAt).format('h:mm a, MMMM DD YYYY')}
                        </Typography>
                        <hr className={classes.invisibleSeparator} />
                        <Typography variabnt="body1">{body}</Typography>
                      </div>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
                {index !== comments.length - 1 && (
                  <hr className={classes.visibleSeparator} />
                )}
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  }

  Comments.propTypes = {
    comments: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  export default withStyles(styles)(Comments);
```

Comment: `comments` prop is undefined initially or at all. You can modify your map like this to remove the error:  `{(comments || []).map((comment, index) => {`. If you don't see any comments rendered then check what you pass to the Comments component.

Comment: Maybe you should use text rather than a screenshot for errors.